# UIImagePickerController front camera show mirror image on preview view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I know many people had asked this question, but I am not found some correct answer to fix this issue,My problem is : **How can I make the photo on preview view(after user tap the capture button,and then go to the preview view to let the user preview) not mirror, can this prossible fix in UIImagePickerController**, I know how to rotate the photo , something in enum in `UIImageOrientation` like `UIImageOrientationUp` , I know what this mean.

## Try 1:

I attend to get the photo after user tap *capture* button before go to the preview view and use the photo which I have mirror to cover the default photo (use `cameraOverlayView`), I can detect the user tap the  *capture* button use `NSNotificationCenter` with **@"_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem"**, but I find no way to get the photo.

## Try 2:

I use `cameraViewTransform`, but when user take photo (front camera) when the *Home* button on the bottom or top, the image on preview view is not mirror, but when the `Home` button on the left or right, the image on phone have some problem before user tap the *capture*, although the image on the preview view is not mirror.use `AVCaptureDeviceDidStartRunningNotification` notification.

```
- (void)cameraChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  if(self.imagePickerController.cameraDevice == UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront)
  {
     self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
     self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, -1, 1);
     if (self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView) {
        NSLog_DEBUG(@"self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView is not nil");
    } else {
        NSLog_DEBUG(@"self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView is nil");
    }
    self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform, -1, 1);
  } else {
    self.imagePickerController.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally, i can not solve this issue in `UIImagePickerController`, but i solve this issue using `AVFoundation` and `CoreMotion`, you can see [AVCam](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)

```
//init the motionManager
- (void)initializeMotionManager{
  motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
  motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = .1;
  motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = .1;

  [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                    withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData  *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error) {
                                            [self outputAccelertionData:accelerometerData.acceleration];
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            NSLog_DEBUG(@"%@", error);
                                        }
                                    }];
  }

//detect the device orientation
- (void)outputAccelertionData:(CMAcceleration)acceleration{

  if (acceleration.x >= 0.75) {
      _orientationNew = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
  }
  else if (acceleration.x <= -0.75) {
      _orientationNew = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
  }
  else if (acceleration.y <= -0.75) {
      _orientationNew = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
  }
  else if (acceleration.y >= 0.75) {
      _orientationNew = UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown;
  }
  else {
      // Consider same as last time
      return;
  }

  if (_orientationNew == _orientationLast)
      return;

  _orientationLast = _orientationNew;
}
```